# call parent widget function from inside dijit checkbox change function lopcated inside dgrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I've got a dijit form checkbox inside an ondemand grid.  The Ondemand grid is part of a dojo widget.  I'd like to call one of the functions in the widget within the checkbox's on change event, but I cant seem to get a reference to the widget.  Here is my code:

```
TicketUnMarkedSet: function (GridData) {

        //set the unmarked ticket information
        gridStore = new Memory({ data: GridData, idProperty: "ID" });
        grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, DijitRegistry]))({
            store: gridStore,
            columns: {
                CheckedOut: {
                    label: "CO",
                    renderCell: function (object, cell) {
                        var CO = true; // check the checked out check box based on data from db
                        if (object.CheckedOut == "No") {
                            CO = false;
                        }
                        var cellContent = domConstruct.create("div", {});
                        var cbox = new CheckBox({
                            checked: CO,
                            name: "idBox"
                        });
                        cbox.placeAt(cellContent);
                        on(cbox, "change", function (evt) {
                            var Staff = "No";
                            if (evt == true) {//check box is checked, flag ticket as checked out
                                Staff = cookie("LoggedInAs")
                            }

                        this.CheckOutTicket(Staff);//how to call CheckOutTicket function (this is the checkbox)

                        });
                        return cellContent;
                    }
                },
     ..more columns
},
CheckOutTicket: function (Staff){
  alert(Staff);
}
```

How can I get a reference to CheckOutTicket function ?

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, but maybe not the best solution.  On the postCreate Event I define a global variable referencing the widget, and then use that variable to call the function from inside the change event for the checkbox

Comment: I follow the same approach

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use [dojo/topic](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/topic.html) to get what you want.

```
on(cbox, "change", function (evt) {
    var Staff = "No";
    if (evt == true) {//check box is checked, flag ticket as checked out
        Staff = cookie("LoggedInAs")
    }

    topic.publish("CheckOutTicket", Staff);
});
```

And somewhere in your parent widget, for i.e. in postCreate

```
this.own(topic.subscribe("CheckOutTicket", this.CheckOutTicket));
```

Now you don't have to care about passing handler from parent to child widget and use global variables.